Bluetooth keypad connected but cannot type (linux)
I am connected to my Debian 12 with bluetoothctl
pair <<MAC_ADDR>>
connect <<MAC_ADDR>>

result :
[Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard]# info
Device E5:E8:00:0E:64:D6 (public)
    Name: Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard
    Alias: Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard
    Class: 0x00002540
    Icon: input-keyboard
    Paired: yes
    Bonded: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    WakeAllowed: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Service Discovery Serve.. (00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v04E8p7021d011B

But no key are working, either numeric or arrows...
note : works on my Windows 11's double-boot.
would you have an idea for me ?
Thanks

Try this:
(Excerpt from a script that does more than shown here, therefore the special use of env-variables)
In a Terminal, at the bash prompt, type:
mac="E5:E8:00:0E:64:D6"
on="bluetoothctl connect $mac";
off="bluetoothctl disconnect $mac";

echo $off;
$off;
echo "sleep 2";
sleep 2;
echo $on;
$on

What it does;
Turn off BT communication, wait 2 seconds, turn it on again.
Add a line with #!/bin/env bash at the top and write it all into a file, then chmod 755 filename and place it in a dir that is included in $PATH - you have a command named filename.
In use under Ubuntu, a Debian derivate.
Gets used as a certain device refuses to initialize properly.
